# Proxyreverse in Apache2 with wordpress

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache, express

I have installed and configured Wordpress on my server using also apach2 virtualhosts.
I made a virtualhost with this config

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>

    ServerAdmin yourluxuryroad@gmail.com
    ServerName yourluxuryroad.com
    ServerAlias www.yourluxuryroad.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/yourluxuryroad
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.yourluxuryroad.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =yourluxuryroad.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /node-yrl-book http://localhost:5000
    ProxyPassReverse /node-yrl-book http://localhost:5000

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/yourluxuryroad/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

As you can see from the config i'm trying to set the ProxyPass directive for redirect the requests recived on the path `/node-yrl-book` to a `nodejs` service ( made using `expressjs` ) at port 5000 but this is not working, instead of getting a redirect to that service i get the 404 Page not found wordpress page.

If I make a request at `my_ip/node-yrl-book` instead it works correctly and i am redirected to the service at port :5000

I suppose that i'm missing something in my configuration but i'm not understanding what..
Maybe is something in wordpress that has to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this, I made an SSL certificate for my website using let's encrypt certbot, This script created a new virtualhost in another file for the https requests ( called /etc/apache2/sites-available/myDomain-le-ssl.conf ) That virtualhost was overriding my proxypass directive, editing also this virtualhost made all work

Comment: so [if](https://yourluxuryroad.com) you use certbot this is the how i managed to solve that issue

Answer (score 0):

You have way too much going on.

`ProxyPass` -or- `DocumentRoot`, not both.

You can either serve the page from apache (by using `DocumentRoot`), or you can serve the page from nodejs (by using `ProxyPass`).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, but actually i'm a bit confused since i started playing with apache yesterday, What do you mean that i can serve the page or from apache or from nodejs, can't i just redirect with proxypass to nodejs? I'm hosting a wp site and actually i can't to id with nodejs, and meanwhile i've built a little api with expressjs, there is not a way that can allow me to redirect the requests into that api that is listening at port 5000?